# Assign Element Name to multiple element's names as a Prefix using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage that allows for dynamically generated content, I want to prefix all the dynamic content names with the name of the hidden element when they're created/before post would be acceptable.

The classes that these dynamically added textboxes are in, are shared across the page so can't easily be used to identify.

I cannot get this to work, I would need to check whether they have the prefix, if they don't, add the prefix

**Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/ycjrunja/2/

**jQuery**

```
$(// can't use class).attr(); // do I need to use this method for each <td> ?
```

**Current Generated Markup:**

```
<input type=hidden name="main[xyz]" />
            <input type=button name="addRow" />
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td><input type=text name="tb1r1" /></td>
          <td><input type=text name="tb2r1" /></td>
         </tr>    
         <tr>
          <td><input type=text name="tb1r2" /></td>
          <td><input type=text name="tb2r2" /></td>
         </tr>   
        </table>
```

**Ideal Generated Markup**

```
    <input type=hidden name="main[xyz]" />
        <input type=button name="addRow" />
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><input type=text name="main[xyz]tb1r1" /></td>
      <td><input type=text name="main[xyz]tb2r1" /></td>
     </tr>    
     <tr>
      <td><input type=text name="main[xyz]tb1r2" /></td>
      <td><input type=text name="main[xyz]tb2r2" /></td>
     </tr>   
    </table>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve by haveing same name to all the inputs. :)

Comment: @Maverick not sure what you mean, from what I see, all names are different.

Comment: @Maverick Apologies for not being clearer, this is just a rendered html example of a massive ASP project, I'm trying to get the prefix to be the same on all the inputs, so that when I save back to the model they know where the list items belong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
$("td input").each(function(){
$(this).attr("name",$("input:hidden").attr("name")+$(this).attr("name" ));
});
```

**Explanation:**

The first line iteratres through all the `<input>` elements inside `<td>` elements.

The second line concantates the `name` of the `<input type = "hidden>"` with the `<input>` element's `name` which is being iterated and assigns it to the `name` of currently iterated element.

The last line ends the function and `each()` method.

> The `<input>` elements must have a name before this script gets executed. The `<script>` tag must be placed just before the closing body tag or use `window.onload` instead, to confirm that the DOM has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

try this one .

```
 $("td input").each(function(){
     $(this).attr("name",$("input:hidden").attr("name")+$(this).attr("name"))
 });
```

Comment: Not too hot with jQuery, could you explain what that's doing please? Looking at it, would that not give it as a suffix?

Comment: we get the list of all INPUTs inside of TDs and set to them new name attribute

Comment: Ah yes see my mistake, thanks will give a go and mark correct when I get it working. :)

Comment: post jsfiddle link here